# How to connect html file in resources folder with Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

My SpringWebConfiguration.class is here:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpringSecurityConfig.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        logger.info("-----configure(HttpSecurity http)");

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/user/**").hasAnyRole("USER")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .loginPage("/login")//
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/userAccountInfo")//
                .failureUrl("/login?error=true")//
                .usernameParameter("username")//
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .permitAll().
                and().rememberMe().rememberMeParameter("remember-me").key("uniqueAndSecret").tokenValiditySeconds(1296000).userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .and()
                .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .deleteCookies("guid")
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .permitAll()
                .and().csrf().disable();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        logger.info("-----configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)");
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }
}
```

My LoginController:

```java
@RestController
public class LoginController() {
@GetMapping("/login")
    public String login(Model model) {
        return "/login";
    }
}
```

My html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <h2>Stacked form</h2>
    <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" name="pswd">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-check">
            <label class="form-check-label">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember me
            </label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I open browser and go to "localhost:8080/login". It returns String "/login", not html login page. Why? Maybe I missed something to connect to my html file. I think my controller need something like an url to connect to html file. I don't understand how it work correctly. Help me please!

Comment: `@RestController` _specifically_ means "this returns REST representations, not view parameters". Use `@Controller`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to modify LoginController

```
@Controller
public class LoginController() {
  @GetMapping("/login")
  public String login(Model model) {
        return "/login";
  }
}
```

If it does not work then convert html to jsp page.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Bean
 public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
  InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
  resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
  resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
  return resolver;
 }  
}
```

Add ViewResolver to your configuration class along with your code.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add a view resolver to your spring configurations.

This ViewResolver allows us to set properties such as prefix or suffix to the view name to generate the final view page URL
Example:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.baeldung.web")
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

@Bean
public ViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    bean.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    bean.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
    bean.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return bean;
}

}
```

For such simplicity of the example, we don't need a controller to process the request.
We only need a simple jsp page, placed in the /WEB-INF/view folder as defined in the configuration.

Source:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-view-resolver-tutorial

Comment: How about thymeleaf?